# Kotlin - creating map with 3 arrays using fold not working

Tags: kotlin

I have an array of customers, each customer has properties `id`, `uuid` and `subCustomer` and other properties that I am not interested in. I would like to do one iteration, where I would create 3 arrays where one would hold `ids`, other `uuids` and third `subcustomers` only.
I have tried to achieve this by using `fold` function like this:

```
customers.fold(
      mapOf(
          "ids" to listOf<String>(),
          "uuids" to listOf<UUID>(),
          "subCustomers" to listOf<String>()
      ))
      { acc, customer ->
        acc["ids"]?.plus(customer["id"])
        acc["uuids"]?.plus(customer["uuid"])
        acc["subCustomers"]?.plus(customer["subCustomer"])
      }
```

With this code I get an error in editor:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Map<String, List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>>
Found:
List<Any?>?
```

I have tried this as well:

```
customers.fold(
      mapOf(
          "ids" to listOf<String>(),
          "uuids" to listOf<UUID>(),
          "subCustomers" to listOf<String>()
      ))
      { acc, customer ->
        mapOf(
            "ids" to acc["ids"]?.plus(customer["id"]),
            "uuids" to acc["uuids"]?.plus(customer["uuid"]),
            "subCustomers" to acc["subCustomers"]?.plus(customer["subCustomer"])
        )
      }
```

But, I get this errors:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>
Found:
List<Any?>?
Type mismatch.
Required:
Map<String, List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>>
Found:
Map<String, List<Any?>?>
```

Comment: _Please_ do not use maps for these things. Write data classes.

Comment: How do I add to a list in a data class?

Answer (score 2):

Write two data classes for your data. One for your customers, and one for the three lists that you want:

```
data class Customer(
    val id: String,
    val uuid: UUID,
    val subCustomer: String,
    )
data class CustomerDataLists(
    val ids: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(),
    val uuids: MutableList<UUID> = mutableListOf(),
    val subCustomers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(),
    )
```

Then, just use a simple for loop to add the data in:

```
val dataLists = CustomerDataLists()
for (customer in customers) {
    dataLists.ids.add(customer.id)
    dataLists.uuids.add(customer.uuid)
    dataLists.subCustomers.add(customer.subCustomer)
}
// now dataLists is filled with customers' data
```

Comment: I would not advise using `var` with mutable lists. I think it should either be `var` with `List` type or `val ` with `MutableList` type

Comment: @Joffrey oh gosh, I forgot I have left the `var` there. I was planning on using immutable lists like the OP had done, but then thought that would create too many lists.

Answer (score 2):

@Sweeper's answer is nice. I believe in any case it's worth using data classes instead of maps for this kind of use case.

Since you don't really have any interactions between the 3 lists in the `fold`, you could also build those lists independently (but it's 3 iterations of course here):

```kotlin
data class Customer(
    val id: String,
    val uuid: UUID,
    val subCustomer: String,
)

data class AggregatedCustomers(
    val ids: List<String>,
    val uuids: List<UUID>,
    val subCustomers: List<String>,
)

val customers: List<Customer> = TODO("get that list from somewhere")

val aggregated = AggregatedCustomers(
    ids = customers.map { it.id }
    uuids = customers.map { it.uuid }
    subCustomers = customers.map { it.subCustomer }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This answer contiains 3 parts:
>
> 1. A better way to solve such problem;
> 2. Why the original code doesn't work;
> 3. Other problems need to pay attention.

##### 1. A better way to solve such problem

Let's assume that the `Consumer` mentioned looks like this:

```kotlin
data class Customer(
    val id: String,
    val uuid: UUID,
    val subCustomer: String,
)
```

It's really not necessary to use function `fold` in such occasion. `For` loop or extension function `forEach` is merely enough:

```kotlin
val customers: List<Customer> = listOf(
    Customer("1", UUID.randomUUID(), "sub-1"),
    Customer("2", UUID.randomUUID(), "sub-2"),
    Customer("3", UUID.randomUUID(), "sub-3"),
)

val ids = mutableListOf<String>() // pay attention. use `mutableListOf` instead of `listOf()`
val uuids = mutableListOf<UUID>()
val subConsumers = mutableListOf<String>()

customers.forEach {
    ids += it.id
    uuids += it.uuid
    subConsumers += it.subCustomer
}
```

##### 2. Why the original code doesn't work

The proposed two pieces of code are in the same pattern:

```kotlin
customers.fold(
    mapOf(
        "ids" to listOf<String>(),
        "uuids" to listOf<UUID>(),
        "subCustomers" to listOf<String>()
    )
) { acc, customer ->
    // ... do something with acc and customer
}
```

We should first make it clear that the last statement in the `fold` scope is the expression to be accumulated. It's like an `acc_n <combine> customer -> acc_(n+1)`, for each customer in `customers` each time, where `<combine>` is where we write our logic. So the first proposed piece of code doesn't work because you might not be aware that something should be returned while writing:

```kotlin
customers.fold(...){ acc, customer ->
    acc["ids"]?.plus(customer.id)
    acc["uuids"]?.plus(customer.uuid)
    acc["subCustomers"]?.plus(customer.subCustomer)
}
```

> In fact, the last statement `acc["subCustomers"]?.plus(...)` is an expression with type `List<Any>?`, kotlin regard it as your "acc_(n+1)", but you propose `mapOf("ids" to ...)` as `acc_0`, which has type `Map<String, ...>`: not the same type as `List<Any>?`. And that's why you got the first error:
>
> ```
> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> Map<String, List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>>
> Found:
> List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>?
> ```
>
> We'll talk about generic types later.

Let's move on the second piece of code. A map is proposed as the last expression in the scope of `fold`, which is also a map:

```kotlin
customers.fold(...) { acc, customer ->
    mapOf(
        "ids" to acc["ids"]?.plus(customer.id),
        "uuids" to acc["uuids"]?.plus(customer.uuid),
        "subCustomers" to acc["subCustomers"]?.plus(customer.subCustomer)
    )
}
```

The simpliest way to eliminate error is using `!!` expression (**not suggested!**):

```kotlin
customers.fold(...) { acc, customer ->
    mapOf(
        "ids" to acc["ids"]?.plus(customer.id)!!,
        "uuids" to acc["uuids"]?.plus(customer.uuid)!!,
        "subCustomers" to acc["subCustomers"]?.plus(customer.subCustomer)!!
    )
}
```

The reason is that kotlin cannot assert acc["ids"] is not null, that's why you use `?.` for a null-safe method invoke. However such invoke make the return type nullable:

```kotlin
val cus: Customer? = Customer("1", UUID.randomUUID(), "sub-1") // cus has type Customer? : nullable
val id1: String = cus?.id // [compile error] Type mismatch. [Required: String] [Found: String?]
val id2: String? = cus?.id // OK
val id3: String = cus?.id!! // If `cus?.id` is null, throw NPE.
```

You've declare `acc_0` (in bracket after `fold`) in type `Map<String, List<T>>` implicitly (we will talk about T later). Just know that T is not a nullable type), but a map with type `Map<String, List<T>?>` was found as `acc_(n+1)`. Types mismatch and the error was shown:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>
Found:
List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>?
```

##### 3. Other problem need to pay attention

An important problem is: What's the type of `acc_0`?

```kotlin
// acc_0: 
mapOf(
    "ids" to listOf<String>(),
    "uuids" to listOf<UUID>(),
    "subCustomers" to listOf<String>()
)
```

Of course type of each expression on the left of `to` is String, and `List<T>` is the type of each expression on the right of it. so it must be `Map<String, List<T>>`. What about `T`? Kotlin try to find the nearest ancessor of String and UUID, and find them both implements `Comparable<?>` and `Serializable`, so that's what you see in the error. That's the type of T:

```
Required:
List<{Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}>
```

This may lead to some unwanted experience:

```kotlin
val map = mapOf(
    "listA" to mutableListOf("233"),
    "listB" to mutableListOf(UUID.randomUUID())
)
val listA = map["A"]!! // MutableList<out {Comparable{String & UUID}> & java.io.Serializable}!>
// generic type "collapse" into `Nothing` for no type can implement both Comparable<String> and Comparable<UUID>
listA.add(Any()) // Type mismatch. [Required: Nothing] [Found: Any]
```

So try not to put lists with different generic type into one map.

Another problem is, when you try to invoke `acc["ids"]?.plus(customer.id)`, you are actually invoking such method (from kotlin `_Collections.kt`)

```kotlin
public operator fun <T> Collection<T>.plus(element: T): List<T> {
    val result = ArrayList<T>(size + 1)
    result.addAll(this)
    result.add(element)
    return result
}
```

A new list is created each time you invoke the method! Try use `mutableListOf()` in replace of `listOf()` for collections that you want to make changes, and use "+=" (or `?.plusAsign()` as null-safe version) operator instead. This may leads to some other problem with the original code (which is too complex to explain why), but for the code in *part 1: A better way to solve such problem*, the `+=` is actually invoking:

```kotlin
public inline operator fun <T> MutableCollection<in T>.plusAssign(element: T) {
    this.add(element)
}
```

which just add value to list without create new ones.